# FeinCMS admin - huge page list horribly slow

Tags: django, django-admin, feincms

I maintain a FeinCMS website containing more than 2000 pages. The page list contains a few list-editable checkboxes. Loading the page list takes horribly long (up to 20 seconds) and even much longer with JavaScript enabled.

It should be possible to load only pages of the top hierarchical level at first, and to fetch the submenus when needed with ajax. It seems there's no plugin or snippet published yet for this purpose. Is there?

Comment: Hey; this is a known issue. There is no solution yet, but here's a (newly created) issue on Github: https://github.com/feincms/feincms/issues/541. Thanks!

Comment: Note that I did an optimising pass over the javascript in FeinCMS last year, which landed in 1.9.0, so if you are using something older than that, please try to update.

Comment: @mji Yes. Upgrading to 1.9 remarkably improves the performance. Thanks for optimising!